# Dynamically add .active class to foundation topbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, html-lists, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation for a clients site where they have the ability to dynamically add and remove pages via Comfy Mexican Sofa (a rails CMS). How would I dynamically add the active class to active li in the topbar?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with `JQuery`, but the exact method depends on how your pages are displayed in the address bar.

The following assumes that the `URL` is as follows:

> http://example.com/page/stuff_not_counted

The code provided will add the value of `page` to the *page* variable. You can then use this to select a `li` element to use the [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) `jQuery` method on to add the class `active`

As you can see currently this code snippet will append that class to all `li` elements on the page. You will want to determine an appropriate [Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) to use to insure only one of the `li` elements gets this class. This is commonly the `id` as shown below.

`$("#" + page)` - This selector function gets the element with id="page" where page is the value in your variable.

**CODE**

```
<script>

// Retrieve current Pathname
var path = $(location).attr('pathname');
// Removes everything before and including the first /
var page = path.split('/')[1]
// Make sure we are working
console.log(page);
$( "#" + page ).addClass( "active" );

</script>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/186/)**

If you need to refactor for a dirrent `URL` syntax or `Selector` method please provide a sample `URL` and `li` element.